# Using AWS Inspector across multiple accounts in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I use AWS Inspector service to work across multiple accounts such that one Inspector service in a lab account can pull information from other accounts?

This doesn't do it:

`import boto3
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='some_account')
client=session.client('inspector')
client.register_cross_account_access_role(roleArn='arn:aws:iam::*my_lab_account*:role/aws-service-role/inspector.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonInspector')`

Basically, trying to centralize assessment using AWS Inspector for all accounts I own.

Comment: When you have two accounts Account A (lab account) and Account B(other account). You need to pass IAM Role of Account B.

Comment: @MohanShanmugam That doesn't work. You cannot assign cross account policy to service account IAM roles. `AWSServiceRoleForAmazonInspector ` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Inspector can push findings to AWS Security Hub which can give you a centralized view of the findings across multiple accounts.

Otherwise, you could write a simple script to pull and display results:

```
    import boto3

    for profile in ["lab1", "dev", "uat"]: # <<< You need profiles for each
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
        client = session.client('inspector')
        
        assessment_run = client.list_assessment_runs() # <<< You need to filter here
        response = client.get_assessment_report(
            assessmentRunArn=assessment_run['assessmentRunArns'][0],
            reportFileFormat='HTML',
            reportType='FINDING'
        )
        
        print(response) # <<< Or gather the HTML and build a single site
```

Note: this is pythonish pseudocode.  You'll need to fix it up to run it but it should get you started.